# MySQL conditions between two tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Table "servers":

```
+----+----------------+
| id | disabled_until |
+----+----------------+
| 1  | 0              |     // disabled_until is an epoch timestamp 
| 2  | 146893210      |     // (irrelevant)
| 3  | 1468969442     |
+----+----------------+
```

Table "server_disables":

```
+----+-----------+-------+----------------+
| id | server_id | tld   | disabled_until |
+----+-----------+-------+----------------+
| 1  | 1         | .com  | 0              |
| 2  | 1         | .org  | 1468969900     |
| 2  | 3         | .com  | 1468969900     |
+----+-----------+-------+----------------+
```

I am trying to make a query which selects rows from **servers** where:

1. There's 0 rows in **server_disables** where server_disables.server_id = servers.id *or*
2. There's 1+ rows in **server_disables** where server_disables.server_id = servers.id and the server_disables.disabled_until is less than a certain time (say, x)

I believe I've created a query which can accomplish #2, but not #1. I don't know where to continue or how to add a case for when there's 0 matching rows in server_disables.
You can see my attempt in `OR d.disabled_until IS NULL` but it isn't working.

Query:

```
SELECT s.* FROM servers s 
INNER JOIN server_disables d ON (d.server_id = s.id AND d.tld = '.com') 
WHERE (s.disabled_until < 1468984373) 
AND (d.disabled_until < 1468984373 OR d.disabled_until IS NULL)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

My question is how to make my query also show rows from the "servers" table where there's 0 rows merged from the `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `LEFT JOIN`, and maybe there are duplicated rows, so you may also need to use `DISTINCT`, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.* FROM servers s 
LEFT JOIN server_disables d ON (d.server_id = s.id AND d.tld = '.com') 
WHERE (s.disabled_until < 1468984373) 
AND (d.disabled_until IS NULL OR d.disabled_until < 1468984373)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I did not know about `LEFT JOIN`. :) It's working perfectly.